# Android Phonegap Mac path variable

Tags: macos, variables, cordova, path

./create results in No Such File or directory. I have added platform-tools and tools in paths.d and I still get this result.

export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/ryan/Documents/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/ryan/Documents/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/tools

following these instructions: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

Comment: Are you in the directory that create resides?

Comment: Actually i just figured out I wasnt, missed out the line "go to the bin folder". Thanks.